# Get list of files from server and Call download function on that list to download content

Tags: java, android, performance, apache, android-intent

I have a web server that stores the files at `http://user.mysite.com/content`
Now all I want to achieve in my android application is to download every files that user can upload on this server, I have created function in android that can download files and stores it into sdcard which is something like this:

```
public void doDownload(){
    try {
        int count;
        URL url = new URL("http://user.mysite.com/content");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        long total = 0;
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int)(total/1024),lengthOfFile/1024);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Download Error: ", e.toString());
    }
}
```

How can I retrive the list of files on server and URL for those files + name of files and download Each one of them on to app using loop?

To get the list of file I have some thing list this:

```
public List clientServerFileList(){
    URL url;
    List serverDir = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://user.mysite.com/content/");           
        ApacheURLLister lister = new ApacheURLLister();         
        serverDir = lister.listAll(url);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR ON GETTING FILE","Error is " +e);
    }
    System.out.println(serverDir);
    return serverDir;   
}
```

My server is: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at user.mysite.com Port 80

Comment: The number of brackets } doesn't seem to match in your first codeblock. Fix this and your code indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Send a POST or GET request to your server. When your server recive this request, response the JSON or XML to the client.
2. Parse the XML or JSON that server response to you, get the filename and ..., you can download the file in the file list.

Comment: Thats not a possible option. I cant have anything done on server side!I need some way to get all the list of files on server.